# Using Multiple xmlReader.ReadToFollowing for multiple elements

Tags: c#, linq, xmlreader

I am trying to get different elements in single xmlreader creation

```
<Records>
   <Teacher>
     <Name>Gladstone<Name>
     <Subject>Chemistry<Subject>
   </Teacher>
   <Student>
     <Name>Jaffrey</Name>
     <Address>Pond Avenue</Address>
</Student>
```

How to read both Teacher and Student. While using ReadToFollwing I could only use either one

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(school.xml))
        {
            while (!xmlReader.EOF)
            {
                if (xmlReader.Name != "Teacher")
                {
                    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Teacher");
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use an `XmlReader` directly, rather than just loading an `XDocument` and using LINQ?

Comment: XDocument is not able to handle the size of the file. @Charlieface

Comment: OK is it like more than 1Gb? So how about you state clearly exactly what elements you are trying to get. It's not clear at the moment, because all your code does is an infinite loop without moving forward, and not clear what you actually want to *do* with the results. And do you expect multiple `Teacher` or `Student` nodes? Please be clear.